# Debugging colors in cascading stylesheets

Tags: css, debugging, colors, background-color

Is there any tool available wherein I may open a CSS file and see a color box next to each `color` and `background-color` rules?

Comment: if i correctly understand your question, there is in PHPStorm. In css files you can see small boxes near style declaration, which shows you color of text, border, background etc.

Comment: @Kasyx - Thank you. Would you happen to know of any other CSS debugger or IDE? Preferably one that doesn't need me to install PHP or Apache.

Comment: Same company, there is Webstorm, which support frontend side developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's plenty. You can do this in Visual Studio with the Web Essentials plugin. Chrome Developer Tools does it. If you use Sublime Text there's a package for that: https://github.com/a-sk/livecss. If you use Notepad++ there's plenty of plugins: http://npp.campulka.net/

It's a matter of a simple Google Search and you'll find want you need.